# Finding the path though a list of vectors

Tags: java, path, geometry, nodes, path-finding

I have a list of 325 nodes on a map of earth.
These nodes map out the planet with shipping routes.

I've tasked to make an method that can find the shortest route in distance from one node to another only using a path of nodes. It needs to be real time and quick as there will be possibly hundreds of boats.

I've looked into A* and Dijkstras solutions but they don't deal with corner well?

I was thinking about using the angle and the distances but I'm not sure how I would implement it.

[image: Map of nodes on earth example - real image has more detail]

Each node on the map is as the following object in an objectMap. Int being the node number.

The nodes and calculations were done within the loading of the app. So we have all of that.

The below class is contained in the objectMap and works nicely.

```
public static class Node
{
    private int nodeNumber;
    private Vector2 pos;
    private int connectedNodes[];

    private ObjectMap<Integer, Node> masterList;
    private ObjectMap<Integer, Float> connectedNodeDistances;
    private ObjectMap<Integer, Float> connectedNodeDegrees;

    public Node(int nodeNumber, float x, float y, int connectedNodes[], ObjectMap<Integer, Node> masterList)
    {
        this.nodeNumber = nodeNumber;

        float areaX = x / MapCreator.WORLD_SCALE;
        float areaY = y / MapCreator.WORLD_SCALE;
        this.pos = new Vector2(areaX / MapCreator.CURRENT_DOWN_SIZE_X, (PolyUtils.getInstance().getScreenPercentageY(1f) - (areaY / MapCreator.CURRENT_DOWN_SIZE_X)) - MapCreator.TOP_EXTRA);

        this.connectedNodes = connectedNodes;
        this.masterList = masterList;
        this.connectedNodeDistances = new ObjectMap<Integer, Float>();
        this.connectedNodeDegrees = new ObjectMap<Integer, Float>();
    }

    public void calculateDistances()
    {
        for(int eachConnectedNode : connectedNodes)
        {
            float angleDegree = new Vector2(this.pos).sub(masterList.get(eachConnectedNode).getPos()).angle();
            connectedNodeDistances.put(eachConnectedNode, this.pos.dst(masterList.get(eachConnectedNode).getPos()));
            connectedNodeDegrees.put(eachConnectedNode, angleDegree);
        }
    }

    public int getNodeNumber() {
        return nodeNumber;
    }

    public float getDistanceFromNode(int number)
    {
        return connectedNodeDistances.get(number);
    }

    public Vector2 getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public int[] getConnectedNodes() {
        return connectedNodes;
    }
}
```

Where I'm stuck is:

```
public Array<Node> getFastestRoute(Vector2 startPos, Vector2 endPos, int numberOfAttempts)
{
    Array<Array<Node>> potentialRoutes = new Array<Array<Node>>();

    int sizeOfShortestRouteNodes = 999999;

    for(int index = 0; index < numberOfAttempts; index++)
    {
        Array<Node> newRoute = getListOfNodes(startPos, endPos, MathUtils.random(-0.75f, 0.75f));
        if(newRoute != null)
        {
            if(newRoute.size < sizeOfShortestRouteNodes)
            {
                potentialRoutes.clear();
                potentialRoutes.add(newRoute);
                sizeOfShortestRouteNodes = potentialRoutes.size;
            }
            else if(newRoute.size == sizeOfShortestRouteNodes)
            {
                potentialRoutes.add(newRoute);
            }
        }
    }

    return getShortestRouteDistance(potentialRoutes);
}

private Array<Node> getListOfNodes(Vector2 startPos, Vector2 endPos, float randomizationSeed)
{
    //TODO Draw as lines as test.

    Array<Node> nodeList = new Array<Node>();
    Array<Node> deadNodes = new Array<Node>();

    int iterations = 0;
    final int maxIterations = 100; //Needs to be low so that boat trip isn't too long also helps performance.

    nodeList.add(getNearestNode(startPos));

    Node lastNode = getNearestNode(endPos);
    Node currentNode = nodeList.first();

    while(true)
    {
        float currentNodeToEndAngle = new Vector2(new Vector2(currentNode.getPos())).sub(endPos).angle();

        //Find closest direction
        Node closestNodeInDirection = null;
        float closestDirection = 361;

        for(int eachConnectedNode : currentNode.getConnectedNodes())
        {
            Node potentialNode = boatNodes.get((eachConnectedNode));

            if(!deadNodes.contains(potentialNode, true))
            {
                float angleToEndNodeFromCurrent = (new Vector2(currentNode.getPos()).sub(potentialNode.getPos()).angle());

                //Randomize the direction from the seed.
                angleToEndNodeFromCurrent = angleToEndNodeFromCurrent * randomizationSeed;

                float differenceInDegrees = Math.abs(angleToEndNodeFromCurrent - currentNodeToEndAngle);

                if(differenceInDegrees < closestDirection)
                {
                    closestDirection = differenceInDegrees;
                    closestNodeInDirection = potentialNode;
                }
            }
        }

        //No new nodes.
        if(closestNodeInDirection == null)
        {
            //Go back and try another route.
            if(nodeList.size > 1)
            {
                nodeList.pop();
                currentNode = nodeList.peek();
            }
        }

        //Adding nodes.
        if(closestNodeInDirection != null && lastNode != closestNodeInDirection)
        {
            nodeList.add(closestNodeInDirection);
            deadNodes.add(closestNodeInDirection);
            currentNode = closestNodeInDirection;
        }
        else if(closestNodeInDirection != null)
        {
            //Last node reached.
            nodeList.add(lastNode);
            return nodeList;
        }

        //Iterations too many.
        iterations++;
        if(iterations >= maxIterations){
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public Array<Node> getShortestRouteDistance(Array<Array<Node>> allNodeRoutes)
{
    Array<Node> shortestRoute = null;
    float shortestRouteLength = 99999f;

    for(int arraysIndex = 0; arraysIndex < allNodeRoutes.size; arraysIndex++)
    {
        Array<Node> nodeArray = allNodeRoutes.get(arraysIndex);

        float lengthOfThisRoute = 0f;

        for(int nodesIndex = 0; nodesIndex < nodeArray.size; nodesIndex++)
        {
            Node nextNode = null;
            Node thisNode = nodeArray.get(nodesIndex);

            if(nodesIndex + 1 < nodeArray.size)
            {
                nextNode = nodeArray.get(nodesIndex + 1);
            }

            if(nextNode != null)
            {
                lengthOfThisRoute += thisNode.getDistanceFromNode(nextNode.getNodeNumber());
            }
        }

        if(lengthOfThisRoute < shortestRouteLength)
        {
            shortestRouteLength = lengthOfThisRoute;
            shortestRoute = nodeArray;
        }
    }

    return shortestRoute;
}
```

Comment: What you're describing is the Traveling Salesman problem - Wikipedia has a good discussion of why it's hard and what some fast "good enough" answers may be.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looking it up.

Comment: What is “the shortest route” you are looking for? The shortest route passing through *all* of the nodes? That would be TSP as Sbodd pointed out. The shortest route passing from a given source node to a given destination node? That would be the direct geodesic, unless there are some additional constraints you didn't mention. The shortest routes between two given positions, as your function signature suggests? Then why do you need any nodes at all?

Comment: Because I'm avoiding obstacles, and yes it would be the direct geodesic. Still having troubles with it. I've created my own algorithm that works nice but it goes backwards sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a well known problem with A* and Dijkstras --- and the solution is to not use either of them.

What you need is an "any-angle" algorithm --- so you should use an algorithm called Theta* instead. This approach properly cuts near the corners while avoiding obstacles.

In fact, it is quite similar to the approach you already came up with! I recommend reading the excellent article here, it is a very good explanation of what to do:
[Theta*: Any-Angle Path Planning for Smoother Trajectories in Continuous Environments](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/theta-star-any-angle-paths/)